# Date dialog form for report is working fine on .accdb format but doesn't work in .accde format

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have wrote this codes in my report.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Report_NoData(Cancel As Integer)
    MsgBox "There is no data for this report. Canceling report..."
    Cancel = -1    '/*If no data cancel report*/
End Sub

Private Sub Report_Close() '/*To close Date dialog form which was hide after report opened*/
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "Report Date Range"
End Sub

Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer) '/*To open Date dialog form*/
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Report Date Range", , , , , acDialog, "Select Report Date"
    If Not IsLoaded("Report Date Range") Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

This code is working fine in .accdb format but doesn't work when I save my database as `.accde` format. Actually, it is not opening the date dialog form but its shows a dialog box "Enter Parameter Value". Please help me to resolve this problem.
[image]

I have written following code in preview Button of Date dialog form.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.Caption = Me.OpenArgs
End Sub

Private Sub Preview_Click()
    If IsNull([Beginning Date]) Or IsNull([Ending Date]) Then
        MsgBox "You must enter both beginning and ending dates."
        DoCmd.GoToControl "Beginning Date"
    Else
        If [Beginning Date] > [Ending Date] Then
            MsgBox "Ending date must be greater than Beginning date."
            DoCmd.GoToControl "Beginning Date"
        Else
            Me.Visible = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

and the query have criteria to filter report as per given date in date dialog form.

> ">=[forms]![Report Date Range]![Beginning Date] And <=[forms]![Report
>   Date Range]![Ending Date]"

Comment: The "Enter Parameter Value" pops up when Access can't find references to DB objects. I think the problem is in your query. Is this form being displayed as a subform? (That changes the path to the form objects relative to the parent form)

Comment: Hello David, thank you for answering. Actually my database is working fine in .accdb format but doesn’t work in .accde format. I believe the code and query criteria is correct. But there is some problem while saving my database as .accde execute only format. I have double checked the criteria by opening date dialog form manually and then I run report. I found it is working. But when I open report it is not opening date dialog form ‘Report date range’ form.

Comment: Have you tried "Compact & Repair"? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/compact-and-repair-a-database-6ee60f16-aed0-40ac-bf22-85fa9f4005b2

Comment: yes I tried many time but I have found that there was some empty private sub like below, I deleted the empty sub now it is ok. Option Compare Database

Private Sub Product_Name_English__Click()

End Sub

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept that as the solution to close this Question out.

Answer (score 1):

I remove empty sub from some forms. now is is working fine.

For example:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Previous_Product_Click()

End Sub
```